# update XCode 4 to latest IOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

how can i update the sdk version that I have in XCode 4.1 (sdk v. 4.3) to IOS SDK version 5 (the latest one) without having to download XCode 4.2 and install all over again ?

Comment: Check Xcode -> Preferences and then the Downloads tab. You may find the SDK under one of the two tabs there as an available download. If not, then you'll need to update to 4.2 for Lion (Mac App Store) or 4.2 for Snow Leopard. (developer center download)

Comment: there is no Downloads tab in there ...

Comment: Aha it must be in v4.2 then. I'd recommend this version anyway - it's not a huge download.

Answer (score 4):

In short I do not think its possible. You have to download the relevant dmg and install on your machine. While installing you can give the option of upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

i have just come across this issue. go to application and delete install xcode, then go to app store and download xcode again.